# AWS Cloudformation Template with variable from current CFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use a value from a current stack when applying a new change-set template.  As you can imagine, many of the current configuration parameters of a stack are going to be needed to re-apply a new set.  However, I can't really find the definitive documentation on how to do this.

So far, I'm looking at something like this.

```
  "DomainName": {
    "Value": {"Ref": "AWS::S3::Bucket::DomainName"}
  }
```

Where I'm hoping the change set generator will use this Ref value to get the current domain name of the configured S3 bucket.

Maybe this is not how change-sets work at all?  I would imagine the configuration is merged with the previous configuration at run-time, so you should have access to some of the previous instance variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you define in CloudFormation template are so called `Resources`.
Example of resources are:

- AWS::S3::Bucket
- AWS::EC2::Instance
- AWS::EC2::VPC

Each resource has `Properties` that you define when declaring them in a CloudFormation template. Let's take `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource as an example.

```json
{
  "Resources" : {

    "MyBucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "BucketName" : "my-bucket-name"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

`BucketName` is a property of "MyBucket" resource.

Resources typically also have `Return Values`. A return value is something that you can use in your CloudFormation templates to build cross-reference logic and relationships between resources. Each resource usually has a "default" return value, and this value is returned when you reference a certain resource using `Ref` intrinsic function within the template. In case of `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource, this "default" return value is simply a `BucketName`. This means that if you would like to use `my-bucket-name` somewhere else in your template, you would use `Ref` intrinsic function on `MyBucket` resource. As an example, we can create `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` resource, `BucketName` (in fact `Bucket`) is one of properties of `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`. Let's do it then:

```json
{
  "Resources" : {

    "MyBucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "BucketName" : "my-bucket-name"
      }
    },

    "MyBucketPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "Bucket" : { "Ref" : "MyBucket" },
        "PolicyDocument" : JSON_STRUCTURE_SKIPPED_FOR_CLARITY
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Note that I didn't write `"Bucket" : "my-bucket-name",` in `MyBucketPolicy` resource above, I actually want to reference `MyBucket` there.
CloudFormation engine will replace `{ "Ref" : "MyBucket" }` value with `"my-bucket-name"` when I deploy the template.

Some resources provide extra `Return Values` (attributes), these values are accessible by using `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function. [AWS::S3::Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#aws-properties-bucket-ref) extra return values / attributes are:

- DomainName
- DualStackDomainName
- WebsiteURL

Syntax of `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function is shown below:

`{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "logicalNameOfResource", "attributeName" ] }`

In order to get `DomainName` from `"AWS::S3::Bucket` resource, you would do it like this:

`{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyBucket", "DomainName" ] }`

You could use `DomainName` for example in CloudFormation stack outputs section. Complete example follows:

```json
{
  "Resources" : {

    "MyBucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "BucketName" : "my-bucket-name"
      }
    },

    "MyBucketPolicy" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties" : {
        "Bucket" : { "Ref" : "MyBucket" },
        "PolicyDocument" : JSON_STRUCTURE_SKIPPED_FOR_CLARITY
      }
    }

  },

  "Outputs" : {

    "MyBucketDomainName" : {
      "Description" : "Domain name of my bucket",
      "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyBucket", "DomainName" ] }
    }
  }
}
```

You will find information about all `Resources`, their `Properties` and `Return Values` (these accessible via `Ref` as well as `Fn::GetAtt` functions) in [AWS Resource Types Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Michal, Definitely helpful.  What I'm still a little unclear on is how you transfer information from a previous configuration into the new template.  Say for example, that I need a previous hard-coded bucket name.  I guess I would add that to outputs and use that with the create-change-set tool?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what is it that you are trying to achieve on high level, do you think you could give me a bit more context?

Comment: Yes, for example in your template above, Imagine MyBucket > BucketName was previously setup using a `Parameter` ref.  But I'd like to change MyBucket > Properties > SomethingElse while maintaining the previous BucketName, but I don't have an `Outputs` to read that value from.  Essentially, I'd like to merge previous a configuration with a new one, but only change one or two properties.

Comment: actually, I figured it out.  I wanted to use "update-stack" not "create-change-set" when you use update-stack, you can use original parameters that were applied or override.